# How to fix Missing CSRF token in sentry

Tags: c++, c, django, sentry

After fighting with sentry when installing it on openshift i got it up and running only to discover that when sending an event to my server it will throw this error:

> 12:30:59 [WARNING] django.request: Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /api/1/envelope/ (status_code=403 request=<WSGIRequest: POST u'/api/1/envelope/'>)
> 10.125.2.1 - - [20/Jul/2020:12:30:59 +0000] "POST /api/1/envelope/ HTTP/1.1" 403 6059 "-" "sentry.native/0.3.4"

If I send a curl request to the API i get a neat HTML webpage that shows the csrf error. Anyone got an idea what might be the problem here?

Comment: The problem is the server sent you a cookie or a token and you didn't use it. Or something like that.

Comment: @user253751 mhm that might be true but according to these docs i dont have to set anything alse than my DSN..https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/native/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proxy `/api/` to sentry relay worker. Relevant part from https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/blob/master/nginx/nginx.conf

```
upstream relay { server relay:3000; }
upstream sentry { server web:9000; }
server {
    location /api/store/ { proxy_pass http://relay; }
    location ~ ^/api/[1-9]\d*/ { proxy_pass http://relay; }
    location / { proxy_pass http://sentry; }
}
```

Comment: done all of this but still getting the same error.

Comment: there is no port 3000 bound though, does Relay have to be started separately from Sentry itself?

Answer (score -1):

You could disable CSRF middleware or if you just want to disable it for this endpoint you can use the @csrf_exempt decorator.

Comment: How can I disable it?

Comment: Go to the settings.py file, find the middleware list and remove the one that contains CSRF ;)

Comment: Sadly this is the docker image...I have no clue where the settings.py can be found